# Bash script entrypoint (PID=1) kills `tail` sub process ONLY if a fake trap (which does NOTHING) was there

Tags: linux, bash, shell, docker, process

I am facing a strange behavior in my `Bash` script, I have this `Bash` script which is running with `PID 1` (it is an `entrypoint` for `Docker` container, if you are not familier with Docker, I assume you can ignore this info).

When I run the following script, `SIGTERM` terminates everything very quickly, and everything seems to be fine (please keep in mind that `sshd` service does not exist! my whole system starts only this script which runs `tail` nothing more, but till now it is not the problem).

```
#!/bin/bash

trap "pkill sshd" SIGTERM

export PATH=/usr/local/samba/bin/:/usr/local/samba/sbin/:$PATH

if [ -f /usr/local/samba/etc/smb.conf ]; then
        exec /usr/local/samba/sbin/samba -i
else
        tail -f /dev/null & wait ${!}
fi
```

The problem comes when I delete that `trap`. now my system hangs, and it seems because tail is till running and does not end for some reason. (if you are familier with Docker, Docker waits for 10 seconds, and then kill the container, because it didn't respond for the `SIGTERM`, again if you are not familier with Docker, ignore this info).

```
#!/bin/bash

export PATH=/usr/local/samba/bin/:/usr/local/samba/sbin/:$PATH

if [ -f /usr/local/samba/etc/smb.conf ]; then
        exec /usr/local/samba/sbin/samba -i
else
        tail -f /dev/null & wait ${!}
fi
```

Could some one explain to me what is the problem exactly? why does that fake `trap` makes everything to work (although it does practically nothing, but it works because it is simply there).

I just still want to mention that using an empty `trap`: `trap "" SIGTERM` doesn't help, something should be there in the trap to work (even if it does nothing).

Hope that someone can help me, thanks!

Comment: also asked at https://serverfault.com/q/869543/30957